# Why dates are being interpreted one day prior in server-rendered templates in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs, meteor-up

I'm using Meteor 1.2, `momentjs` for dates and `meteor-up` ( `mup` ) for deployment.

Before persisting to MongoDB, the date value from the input field is run through,

```
moment( <date>, "DD MM YYYY" ).toISOString()
```

When pulling from MongoDB, and before plonking it into the template, I run it through,

```
moment( <date>, moment.ISO_8601 ).format( "DD-MM-YYYY" )
```

I have templates that render both on the client and on the server ( using the `meteorhacks/meteor-ssr` package )

So here's the issue.

On the production server ( Ubuntu 14.04 ), the dates when outputted on the server-side templates are always one day prior to the actual day.
For example, if the date is `01-08-2015`, the markup rendered on the server shows `31-07-2015`.

This issue does not exist on server-side templates when I run the application locally and on client-side templates in general.

How do I figure this out?

Comment: You must be EAST of UTC?

Comment: You lost the time zone when you saved as string :( Really not recommended as you can no longer do date queries, sort correctly, or convert to the user's tz.

Comment: @MichelFloyd—you can't lose the time zone from "DD MM YY", there isn't one. ;-)

Comment: I'm in Bangalore and the app is being used here as well. We are using a server in Singapore. I switched to a server in Bangalore itself but the problem still persisted, so I switched back to the Singapore one.

The timezone here is UTC+5:30.
@MichelFloyd My intention is to store dates in an agnostic format. Isn't the ISO 8601 format agnostic?

Comment: @RobG - you're right that the tz was lost on input, he never has a real date object.

Comment: @aditya—when you parse a string date without a time zone, it will usually be treated as local i.e. the host system offset will be applied so that it represents 00:00:00 on that date. When you convert that back to a string in ISO 8601 format, the time zone is preserved so if the host is +0530, then starting with 01-08-2015 you'll get a date for 2015-08-01T00:00:00+0530. If this is converted to an ISO 8601 for GMT, you'll get  2015-07-31T18:30:00Z. I.e. it's 5:30 earlier.

Comment: @aditya—also note that an ISO 8601 date–only string is treated as GMT by ECMAScript, which is inconsistent with ISO 8601, which specifies that they should be treated as local.

Answer (score 0):

When I save my dates I save it as a date object:

```
import {Posts, Comments} from '../../lib/collections';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {check} from 'meteor/check';

export default function () {

  Meteor.methods({
    'posts.create'(_id, title, content, userId) {
      check(_id, String);
      check(title, String);
      check(content, Object);
      check(userId, String);

      const publishedAt = new Date();
      const post = {_id, title, content, userId, publishedAt};
      Posts.insert(post);
    }
  });
```

In my Mongo database it saves like this:
"$date": "2016-07-25T22:14:35.563Z"

Timezone and all...Hope this helps

Comment: I've read that the native Date API is [buggy](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/) and inconsistent. In my application, an explicit date is entered by the user which I then parse with `moment`. Is this a safe use-case for native Date API?

Comment: @aditya—the built–in Date isn't buggy, however date string parsing is inconsistent **by design**.

Comment: @tmpg—parsing strings with the Date constructor is the one aspect of the built–in Date that is extremely inconsistent and strongly recommended against. For parsing, **always** use a bespoke function or library and specify the parse format, otherwise you are leaving it entirely to chance.